# Problem with the synchronisation of eeg and tobii eye tracking data using eeglab through EYE-EEG toolbox

Tags: matlab, eye-tracking, eeglab

I am not able to synchronize and import the EEG and eye tracking data, the error is showing there is no trigger or event information in the parsed eye tracking data but the trigger information is present and still the error is popping up.

```
pop_importeyetracker(): Loading C:\Users\gupta\OneDrive\Documents\MATLAB\eeglab_current\eeglab2023.1\27FebEEG_ETData\Mohit27Feb3.mat...
pop_importeyetracker(): Found no trigger/event information in your parsed eye tracking data (ET.event)!
See the help of the pop_parse >your Eyetracker< function and read the plugin description.
```

I tried following every step mentioned on the website and was expecting the data to be synchronized but still it didn't happen.